# ClientSide Notification for failed Login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node.js project where I can fill a login form which will be send to my server.js as url params. If the sent data can be verified as registered, the client will be logged in. My Problem is now how do notificate the client when it didn't work? 
My login.html contains a div which will be shown if it's triggered by my login.js file. But how do I activate the trigger, can I send url params to client and change the site's behaviour?

**server.js**

```
app.get("/signUp/:username/:password", (req, res) => {
    auth.signUp({
        username: req.params.username,
        password: req.params.password
    }, (result) => {
        if (result) {
            res.redirect("../../index.html");
        } else {
            res.redirect("../../index.html");
            // res.send("Login failed");
        }
    })
})
app.get("/signIn/:username/:password", (req, res) => {
    auth.signIn({
        username: req.params.username,
        password: req.params.password
    }, (result) => {
        if (result) {
            res.redirect("../../index.html");
        } else {
            res.send("Login failed");
        }
    })
})
```

**login.js** Client-Side

```
signIn = () => {
    let user = document.getElementById('signDiv-username').value;
    let pass = document.getElementById('signDiv-password').value;
    hideErrorLog();
    window.location.replace("/signIn/" + user + "/" + pass);
}
signUp = () => {
    let user = document.getElementById('signDiv-username').value;
    let pass = document.getElementById('signDiv-password').value;
    hideErrorLog();
    window.location.replace("/signUp/" + user + "/" + pass);
}

hideErrorLog = () => {
    let errorLog = document.getElementById("error-log");
    errorLog.style.display = "none";
    errorLog.innerText = "";
}
showErrorLog = (signUp) => {
    let errorLog = document.getElementById("error-log");
    errorLog.style.display = "block";
    if (signUp) {
        errorLog.innerText = "Benutzername existiert bereits!";
    } else {
        errorLog.innerText = "Benutzername/Passwort falsch!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your res.send will replace the entire page and the client side javascript with the string "login failed". you should either send the credentials via ajax call or use templating on server side like ejs templates and use res.render.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have been calling SignUp and SignIn APIs by using window.location.replace() and you are just replacing username and password as a part of the url which is not the way to make API calls AFAIK. And also never pass sensitive data like username and password in the URL, send them as part of body of the request.

You need to make use of [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and call showErrorLog() inside the catch() which means there's error in the API call.

Sample fetch code

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    // Add some code here
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    // call showErrorLog() here
  });
```